# Let G be a simple group of order 168.What is the number of subgroups of G of order 7?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know ,what is simple group.But unable to find its ans. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

By Sylow's theorems the number $n$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $7$.
Also $n\mid 168$, so $n\mid 24$. I think that only allows $n=1$
or $n=8$. One of these possibilities can be dismissed by simplicity.